# use a string with newlines in javascript

Tags: javascript, jinja2

I'm using a template engine and have the following JavaScript code

```
 <script>
    alert('{{entity.body}}');
 </script>
```

Unfortunately the body has new line characters so the script throws a syntax error because it's looking for a `\` in a multiline string. What's the standard way to deal with this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Why is there an error ? This doesn't make an error : `​alert('aa\nbb');​​​​​​​​​​`

Comment: I get you're not using only javascript. Are you using a templating system ? Which one ?

Comment: OK. Added the tag. As your bug is related to your template system, now it may make sense.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on your templating language, you may be able to pass the value into a "filter". By default they expect an HTML environment.

I never heard of "Jinja", but it has filters.

```
alert('{{entity.body | replace("\n", "\\n")}}');
```

Or write a custom filter that does what you want.

Comment: alert('{{entity.body | replace("\n","\\n") | replace("\r","")}}');

Answer (score 1):

You could

```
<script id="entity_body" type="text/pain">{{entity.body}}</script>
```

and then:

```
alert( document.getElementById('entity_body').innerHTML );
```

So, you put the output in a non-executing script blog, and then retrieve that text with JavaScript.

Comment: I wouldn't compensate problems I have with a templating language by making them somebody else's problems (JavaScript).